# facing error with RowMapper and JdbcTemplate's update method

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

```
public class PersonDAO {

    private JdbcTemplate jdbc ;

    public void setDataSource(DataSource jdbc){
        this.jdbc = new JdbcTemplate(jdbc);
    }

    public List GetPersonDetails(){

        return jdbc.query("select * from person", new RowMapper(){

            public Person mapRow(ResultSet rs, int rowNum) throws SQLException {
               Person person = new Person();
               person.setName(rs.getString("Name"));
               person.setEmail(rs.getString("Email"));
               person.setPhone(rs.getInt("Phone"));
               person.setSex(rs.getString("Sex"));
                return person;
            }

        });
    }

    public boolean InsertPersonDetail(Person person){


    BeanPropertySqlParameterSource params = new BeanPropertySqlParameterSource(person);

    return  jdbc.update("insert into Person (Name , Email , Text ,Phone) values ( :Name , :Email , :Text ,:Phone)" , params)== 1;

        }
    }
```

I am facing 2 error which i am not able to figure out :

1. Type `RowMapper` is not generic
2. I'm not able to do an update with `BeanPropertySqlParameterSource` object as a parameter.

Comment: What exceptions? Is the first one a compile time error ? Share more details

Comment: `BeanPropertySqlParameterSource` is for use with a `NamedParameterJdbcTemplate` and not a plain `JdbcTemplate`. `RowMapper` is generic unless you use some old version of Spring.